# Mounting VueJS to top level div & user submitted content

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building an small guide website which allows users to submit articles about a game. There are a number of components on the website written in Javascript, using VueJS. The majority of the site is powered by Laravel and renders in plain HTML except these components. At the moment, I have VueJS mounted to #app, or my top level div element, as is default with the Laravel configuration.

I then drop components into the page as usual (<my-component>) and VueJS will pick these up and render them appropriately. Awesome.

However, there are a few situations where user submitted content will actually break the page. For example, if double brackets are used {{ example }}, this is VueJS syntax, and it will pick up the tags and refuse to render the page. Another example is if I need to use <script> tags in the body which aren't VueJS, for example embedding a Twitch TV stream.

It seems like because Vue is mounted to #app, absolutely everything inside that shares VueJS syntax or is a script tag will break the page.

Is mounting to #app the wrong idea? Should I be splitting all of my components and somehow launching them with more granularity? I really like the approach of just dropping in Vue components into code with <this-syntax>.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the interpretation of the curly braces from Vue.js by Laravel's blade engine by using an `@` in front of them. They will remain untouched by PHP this way and will leave them to get picked up by Vue.js

`Hello, @{{ name }}.`

Check out the section on javascript frameworks:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understood the question - Vue picking up the brackets is the problem here.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible since the double brackets are rendered by a server side language and only then javascript gets to interpret what has already been parsed.